# Return list of subtype object from extended list of supertype

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance, extends

I declared list which contains elements of `ClassA`:

```
public class SuperList<E> extends ArrayList<ClassA> {

  public SuperList<E> getSomeElements() {
    SuperList<E> resultList = new SuperList<>();
    // creating result list
    return resultList;
  }
}
```

I have a class `ClassB`:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA  {
  // class definition
}
```

And finally I have `SuperList` with instances of ClassB. I want to get elements from it by method `getSomeElements()` and iterate over it:

```
SuperList<ClassB> bigList;

SuperList<ClassB> elements = bigList.getSomeElements();
for(ClassB element : elements){
  // do something
}
```

But IntelIJ says something like that:

> Incompatibile types. Required: ClassB. Found: ClassA.

Can I do it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
public class SuperList<E extends ClassA> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public SuperList<E> getSomeElements() {
        SuperList<E> resultList = new SuperList<>();
        // creating result list
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Then, if `bigList` is a `SuperList<ClassB>`, the compiler will know that `bigList.getSomeElements()` is also a `SuperList<ClassB>`.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.